# Random figures in the matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, random

Consider the matrix 'm1' :

```
m1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
```

Let's pick one of the elements of this matrix.
It will be the center (point of intersection of the diagonals) of the rectangle with sides (a, b) and the slope angle of the side 'b' alpha (0, 90 degrees):
[image]

For a -> 20, b -> 10, m -> 50, n -> 30, [Alpha] -> Pi/6:

The length of the side of the rectangle is the number `(0, Dimensions [m1] [[1]]`).
The question is what elements of the matrix 'm1' are in the area of this rectangle, setting the result in the form of a matrix of numbers (rows and columns). If there are not all elements of columns or rows, the element in the matrix will be empty.
We do not include rectangles that are outside the matrix 'm1':

[image]

For `a -> 20, b -> 10, m -> 50, n -> 30, \[Alpha] -> Pi/6`
[image]

,where gray dots are blank spaces in the matrix.
By the way. Why are the corners not completely filled with red dots? Does it just seem so?
In addition, the code takes into account incomplete rectangles, e.g. a -> 20, b -> 10, m -> 10, n -> 3, \ [Alpha] -> Pi / 6. Maybe such a limitation can be done by counting the area of a rectangle?

Answer (score 8):

For better visualization, I will use an image of a house instead of a random matrix.

```
m1 = ImageData[
   ColorConvert[
    ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}], {100, 100}], 
    "Grayscale"]];

params = {a -> 30, b -> 60, m -> 30, n -> 50, α -> Pi/6};

pts = Catenate@Table[{i, j}, {i, 100}, {j, -1, -100, -1}];
reg = TranslationTransform[{m, -n}][
   RotationTransform[α][Rectangle[{-a/2, -b/2}, {a/2, b/2}]]];

regMem = RegionMember[reg /. params];
ptsInside = Select[pts, regMem];
span = Span @@@ Sort@*Abs@*MinMax /@ Transpose@ptsInside;

m2 = ReplacePart[m1, {{i_, j_}} :> 0 /; Not@regMem[{i, -j}]];
m3 = Part[m2, Sequence @@ span];

Row[ArrayPlot[ReleaseHold@#, ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {HoldForm@m1, HoldForm@m2, HoldForm@m3}]
```

[image: Cropped matrix]

Comment: >>>>> However, they are now presented simply as a 1D list, not yet as a matrix ...>>> That's not good. But, thanks for help!

Comment: @ralph, honestly, I do not quite understand how you want torepresent this rectangle as a matrix. The elements are obviously not aligned into rows and columns – your image with orange rectangle and black dots is not an accurate representations. Take my image, and please show us how the red dots should be put in a matrix.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: @ralph, first of all, there are no missing corners in my image. Stare for a while at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3b89.png) to see where the "illusion of missing corners" come from. Secondly, according to your update, you do not want your final matrix to be somehow re-rotated, but you just want to get the "bounding rectangle" (orange), keep the red elements, and set the grey elements to zero (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptv6Q.png)). This is now the matrix you want – am I correct?

Comment: Yes. I give up the matrix rotation. My last image is ok. The border of the matrix where the gray elements are eg zeros, are the extreme red points of the rectangle.

Comment: <<<<keep the red elements, and set the grey elements to zero (see this image). This is now the matrix you want – am I correct?<<<  Yes. It is correct matrix.

Comment: @ralph, see my update.

Comment: thanks! Good work.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to speed it up? For large sets and output matrices it is quite slow. The 'bottleneck' is: ptsInside = Select[pts, regMem]; and m2 = ReplacePart[m1, {{i_, j_}} :> 0 /; Not@regMem[{i, -j}]];

Comment: Yes, this line is slow because (i) ``ReplacePart`` is generally notoriously slow, and (ii) ``RegionMember`` is also slow. What you can do is to first crop the matrix and then mask it, which will make it faster (because it will be working on a smaller matrix). Or, since you have a fairly simple region (rotated rectangle), you could try extracting explicitly all four boundary lines, then creating a compiled function that mask the matrix by simple algebraic inequalities (not using ``RegionMember``).

Comment: Thanks. See my update

Comment: @ralph it is better to make new questions as a separate post instead of continuously editing these new inquiries into your question. By continuing to “move the goalpost” as the phrase goes, you make it difficult for others to answer your questions & satisfy your continually changing requirements. It is better to separate these out rather than to try to combine them all into one single amalgamated question.